# How do I show that a derivative function that's bounded on $I$ then constants A and B exists such as $ |f(x)|≤Bx+A$?

Tags: calculus

If $I ⊂ R$  is an open interval and $f:I→R$  be an arbitrary derivative function, how can I show that when $ f′$ is bounded on $ I$ , then there are constants $ A$  and $ B$  so that $ |f(x)|≤B|x|+A$  for all $ x∈I$?

Comment: Use the mean value theorem.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: So $(-\infty,\infty)$ does not qualify as open interval?

Answer (score 0):

Obs: The problem is not true with the actual statement. Consider the identity map on $(-\infty,0)$. As $x$ goes to $-\infty$, the value $Bx+A$ goes to $-\infty$, $\forall A,B\in\mathbb{R}$ as well. So there are two possibilities:

1) We suppose that the interval is bounded, or

2) We change "$|f(x)|\leq Bx+A$" by "$|f(x)|\leq B|x|+A$"

In both cases the following idea applies:

Let $K=\underset{x\in I}{sup} |f'(x)|$. As suggested by mfl, mean value theorem asserts that $|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)||x-y|$ for some $c\in[x,y]$ (assuming $x\leq y$). This implies

$|f(x)|-|f(y)| \leq |f(x)-f(y)| \leq K|x-y| \leq K|x|+K|y|$.

Fix $y_{0}\in I$, then put $B=K$, $A=K|y_{0}|+|f(y_{0})|$

Comment: Yup, it was a mistake, it should be B|x|, fixed it

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it? I really can't even though I tried. I went to as far as using the MVT but couldn't go further. That's my problem.

Comment: Which part of my proof you don't understand?

Comment: The = $A = K|y0| + f(y0)$

Comment: I claim that those constants are the ones we are looking for. Do you agree? We need to check the definition

Comment: Oooh got it! Thaank you

Comment: BTW, on $(-\infty,0)$, the expression $Bx+A$ can still go to $+\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$. Only $(-\infty,\infty)$ is problematic